# При обновлении число прибавляется дважды

Tags: mysql

Делаю обновление

```
UPDATE `goods` gs 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT * 
             FROM order_elements 
             WHERE order_id=25 ) oe ON gs.san=oe.san 
SET gs.quantity=gs.quantity+oe.quantity;
```

Число oe.quantity прибавляется дважды хоть одна строка, хоть три
В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Если вместо Update сделать SELECT запрос (оставив все джойны) и выведя на экран то, что планируется присвоить, то результат получаете такой какой нужен?

Comment: Не верю. Вот [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0be725ac3b4d2d417a3b48bedf7187d9) - откорректируйте структуру и данные так, чтобы воспроизвести описываемую проблему. PS. Предположу, что запрос на обновление вызывается на исполнение дважды. Смотрите General Log.

Comment: На fiddle данные добавляются один раз. Спасибки. Придеться искать второй вызов =(

Comment: В чем прикол я не знаю, но phpMyAdmin через окно SQL выполняет запрос дважды(dybpe d rjycjkb gjzdkztncz pfghjc ldf;ls). Через консоль внизу все окей. Проблема была в этом =)